# Regex - Repeating a capture group pattern in a cleaner way

Tags: python, regex

I'm beginning to study regex, and I got the following question. The text is below:

```
00 0-23/2 * *   *   ubuntu  source /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/  .........
10 17 8 1,3,6,12 * ubuntu source /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/   .............
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( .....................
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( ......................
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron ||....................
```

I used this regex, with `python re` package:

```
"[\d\*,/-]+\s{1,}[\d\*,/-]+\s{1,}[\d\*,/-]+\s{1,}[\d\*,/-]+\s{1,}[\d\*,/-]+"
```

It returns me the first 5 numerical informations of each line. But it's not good to write `[\d\*,/-]+` 5 times...

I tried things like `(([\d\*,/-]+)\s{1,}){5}`, `(?([\d\*,/-]+)\s{1,}){5}` or variations with the `()` notation, intending to get the capture group of interest and repeat it.

My feeling is that I haven't understood the notation or there is another appropriate syntax to solve what I want to solve (avoid the `[\d\*,/-]+` repetition).

Could you help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps `(?:[\d\*,/-]+\s+){5}`? https://regex101.com/r/FyaXec/1

Comment: Thank you, Nick! Now i see that I was making so much mistakes, but now I got it! I tried with (?:), but in a wrong way. Also, `\s+` is much cleaner than `\s{1,}`. Really thank you!

Comment: No worries - I'm glad that was useful.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want to keep the captured data you may just be missing a capturing group wrapped around your repeated capturing group so that your regex captures more than just the last occurrence.

```
(([\d*,/-]+\s+){5})
```

Used something like so:

```
import re
inputString = ...
expression = re.compile("(([\d*,/-]+\s+){5})")
matches = expression.findall(inputString)
print(matches)
```

References that may be useful:

- https://regex101.com/r/3fRfCb/1 (I highly recomment this, gives you a full breakdown)
- https://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html

Comment: Thanks, Iessa! This site, regex101, is really nice! I liked it!

Comment: Your parenthesis are unbalanced, you missed the asterisk and why do you escape slash and hyphen?

Comment: They are indeed, nice spotting. Hyphen is a special character for range, the forward slash, who knows felt like it at the time.